# How to add borders for SnackBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm doing system messages, I decided to use SnackBar, but I ran into a problem - I can't add a border around the SnackBar, I need to make a colored border. Please tell me, is it possible to add a border to the SnackBar and how? Perhaps there are packages that allow you to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text('test'),
      action: SnackBarAction(
        label: 'test label',
        textColor: Colors.white,
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 1),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
)
```

Point is `behavior`, `shape`

Comment: Another question, but do not know how to add a gradient for the border color?

Comment: @Max

There is no way in SnackBar
If you want full customization, I recommend using a container from the bottom sheet.
ref : https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-beginners-guide-to-using-the-bottom-sheet-b8025573c433